# Unable to fetch system locale in perl on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, locale, setlocale

I am new to perl and I need to fetch the current system locale programmatically in perl on Windows.
The way I am doing it is:

```
use locale;
use POSIX(locale_h);
$mylocale = setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
```

Here, even though, I have set my locale as 'en-gb', I am getting 'C' as the locale.

What is wrong/missing here?

Note: when I use setlocale method from a c++ program, it gives me locale as English_UnitedKingdom.

Comment: [Can't replicate](https://pastebin.com/58LazP4x). Please back up your claims with a similar demonstration.

Comment: Wait, Windows? But this is for POSIX locales. Windows doesn't use POSIX locales, so I wonder how you can claim  "I have set my locale as 'en-gb'"

Comment: I have set the locale using Windows UI ie manually changed the locale and now I want to fetch the currently set locale using a perl script.

Comment: Searching CPAN for "Windows locale" immediately finds Win32::Locale, which look like it might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, although I first have to install Win32::Locale using cpan. Is there no platform independent way to fetch locale? becuase I will have to then use Win32::Locale for windows and POSIX setlocale for Unix like flavours. And so the reason why I was able to see correct locale in c++ program is because c support POSIX?

Comment: Re "*Is there no platform independent way to fetch locale?*", Yes, `setlocale` is a platform indepdent way to fetch a unix locale. Windows doesn't have those, so there is nothing to fetch

Comment: You're really asking for platform-independent way of fetching locale information, which presumes the existence of a cross-platform locale system which is able to handle the locale systems of all supported platforms.I don't know if anyone's bothered to do something like that for Perl. Would be a fair amount of work to create and maintain this system-agnostic locale system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Windows locale (as opposed to a non-existent POSIX locale) in a POSIX-style format, you can [Win32::Locale](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Locale)'s `get_locale`.

```
>perl -e"use Win32::Locale qw( ); CORE::say Win32::Locale::get_locale()"
en_ca
```

That's mostly a guess. Windows locales are really numbers.

```
>perl -e"use Win32::Locale qw( ); CORE::say sprintf '0x%X', Win32::Locale::get_ms_locale()"
0x1009
```